# How to animate a text around an oval shape?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, css-animations

I am trying to animate text around an oval like this:

[image: CSS text animation around oval]

I found solutions with circle, but when I transform circle in oval animation is breaks.

Is anyone know how to do this? I would be grateful for any help.

Code for circle:

```js
var radius = 200; // adjust to move out items in and out
var fields = $('.carousel__item'),
  container = $('.carousel'),
  width = container.width(),
  height = container.height();
var angle = 0,
  step = (2 * Math.PI) / fields.length;
fields.each(function() {
  var x = Math.round(width / 2 + radius * Math.cos(angle) - $(this).width() / 2);
  var y = Math.round(height / 2 + radius * Math.sin(angle) - $(this).height() / 2);
  if (window.console) {
    console.log($(this).text(), x, y);
  }
  $(this).css({
    left: x + 'px',
    top: y + 'px'
  });
  angle += step;
});
```

```css
.carousel {
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  margin: 10px auto;
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 50%;
  animation: spin 60s linear infinite;
}

.carousel:hover {
  animation-play-state: paused;
}

.carousel:hover .carousel__item {
  animation-play-state: paused;
}

.carousel__item {
  text-align: center;
  width: 300px;
  position: absolute;
  animation: spin 60s linear infinite reverse;
  font-size: 1.4rem;
}

@keyframes spin {
  100% {
    transform: rotate(1turn);
  }
}

.carousel__item:hover {
  animation-play-state: paused;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="carousel">
  <div class="carousel__item">TEXTTEXTTEXT</div>
  <div class="carousel__item">TEXTTEXTTEXTTEXT</div>
  <div class="carousel__item">TEXTTEXTTEXTTEXT</div>
  <div class="carousel__item">TEXTTEXTTEXTTEXT</div>
  <div class="carousel__item">TEXTTEXTTEXTTEXT</div>
  <div class="carousel__item">TEXTTEXTTEXTTEXT</div>
  <div class="carousel__item">TEXTTEXTTEXTTEXT</div>
  <div class="carousel__item">TEXTTEXTTEXTTEXT</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an idea where you don't need complex calculation and you only have to control the shape using width/height. The text will always rotate around the border so it can be either a circle (width = height) or ellipsis (height != width).

You only need JS to set a different delay for each element.

```js
var delay = 0,
  step = 5 / $('.carousel__item').length; /* 5 is the animation duration */
$('.carousel__item').each(function() {
  $(this).css('animation-delay', -delay + "s");
  delay += step;
})
```

```css
.carousel {
  width: 400px;
  height: 200px;
  margin: 20px auto;
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 1px solid;
}

.carousel__item {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  animation: 
    move-x 5s linear infinite, 
    move-y 5s linear infinite;
  font-size: 1.4rem;
}

.carousel:hover .carousel__item {
  animation-play-state: paused;
}

@keyframes move-x {
  0% {
    left: 0;
    animation-timing-function: ease-in;
  }
  25% {
    left: 50%;
    animation-timing-function: ease-out;
  }
  50% {
    left: 100%;
    animation-timing-function: ease-in;
  }
  75% {
    left: 50%;
    animation-timing-function: ease-out;
  }
  100% {
    left: 0%;
    animation-timing-function: ease-in;
  }
}

@keyframes move-y {
  0% {
    top: 50%;
    animation-timing-function: ease-out;
  }
  25% {
    top: 0;
    animation-timing-function: ease-in;
  }
  50% {
    top: 50%;
    animation-timing-function: ease-out;
  }
  75% {
    top: 100%;
    animation-timing-function: ease-in;
  }
  100% {
    top: 50%;
    animation-timing-function: ease-out;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="carousel">
  <div class="carousel__item">TEXT</div>
  <div class="carousel__item">TEXT</div>
  <div class="carousel__item">TEXT</div>
  <div class="carousel__item">TEXT</div>
  <div class="carousel__item">TEXT</div>
  <div class="carousel__item">TEXT</div>
  <div class="carousel__item">TEXT</div>
  <div class="carousel__item">TEXT</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use offset-path, supported only in modern browsers, to achieve that .

To calculate the path of an ellipse, you can use this [page](http://complexdan.com/svg-circleellipse-to-path-converter/)

```css
.carousel {
  position: relative;
  left: 300px;
  top: 100px;
}

.carousel__item {
  position: absolute;
  offset-path: path('M-200,0a200,100 0 1,0 400,0a200,100 0 1,0 -400,0');
  offset-rotate: 0deg;
  animation: elipse 4s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes elipse {
  0% {
    offset-distance: 100%;
  }
  100% {
    offset-distance: 0%;
  }
}

.carousel__item:nth-child(2) {
  animation-delay: calc(-4s * 1 / 8);
}

.carousel__item:nth-child(3) {
  animation-delay: calc(-4s * 2 / 8);
}

.carousel__item:nth-child(4) {
  animation-delay: calc(-4s * 3 / 8);
}

.carousel__item:nth-child(5) {
  animation-delay: calc(-4s * 4 / 8);
}

.carousel__item:nth-child(6) {
  animation-delay: calc(-4s * 5 / 8);
}

.carousel__item:nth-child(7) {
  animation-delay: calc(-4s * 6 / 8);
}

.carousel__item:nth-child(8) {
  animation-delay: calc(-4s * 7 / 8);
}
```

```html
<div class="carousel">
  <div class="carousel__item">TEXTTEXTTEXT</div>
  <div class="carousel__item">TEXTTEXTTEXTTEXT</div>
  <div class="carousel__item">TEXTTEXTTEXTTEXT</div>
  <div class="carousel__item">TEXTTEXTTEXTTEXT</div>
  <div class="carousel__item">TEXTTEXTTEXTTEXT</div>
  <div class="carousel__item">TEXTTEXTTEXTTEXT</div>
  <div class="carousel__item">TEXTTEXTTEXTTEXT</div>
  <div class="carousel__item">TEXTTEXTTEXTTEXT</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

The equation of an ellipse is similar to that of a circle, but there is a different radius for the X and Y. Just add that!

```js
var radiusX = 100; // adjust to move out items in and out
var radiusY = 60;
var fields = $('.carousel__item'),
    container = $('.carousel'),
    width = container.width(),
    height = container.height();
var angle = 0,
    step = (2 * Math.PI) / fields.length;
fields.each(function() {
    var x = Math.round(width / 2 + radiusX * Math.cos(angle) - $(this).width() / 2);
    var y = Math.round(height / 2 + radiusY * Math.sin(angle) - $(this).height() / 2);
    $(this).css({
        left: x + 'px',
        top: y + 'px'
    });
    angle += step;
});
```

```css
.carousel {
  width: 400px;
  height: 200px;
  margin: 10px auto;
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 50%;
  animation: spin 10s linear infinite;
}
 .carousel:hover {
  animation-play-state: paused;
}
 .carousel:hover .carousel__item {
  animation-play-state: paused;
}
 .carousel__item {
  text-align: center;
  width: 300px;
  position: absolute;
  animation: spin 10s linear infinite reverse;
  font-size: 1.4rem;
}
 @keyframes spin {
  100% {
   transform: rotate(1turn);
 }
}
 .carousel__item:hover {
  animation-play-state: paused;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="carousel">
<div class="carousel__item">-</div>
<div class="carousel__item">-</div>
<div class="carousel__item">-</div>
<div class="carousel__item">-</div>
<div class="carousel__item">-</div>
<div class="carousel__item">-</div>
<div class="carousel__item">-</div>
<div class="carousel__item">-</div>
<div class="carousel__item">-</div>
<div class="carousel__item">-</div>
<div class="carousel__item">-</div>
<div class="carousel__item">-</div>
<div class="carousel__item">-</div>
<div class="carousel__item">-</div>
<div class="carousel__item">-</div>
<div class="carousel__item">-</div>
<div class="carousel__item">-</div>
<div class="carousel__item">-</div>
<div class="carousel__item">-</div>
<div class="carousel__item">-</div>
<div class="carousel__item">-</div>
<div class="carousel__item">-</div>
<div class="carousel__item">-</div>
<div class="carousel__item">-</div>
<div class="carousel__item">-</div>
<div class="carousel__item">-</div>
<div class="carousel__item">-</div>
<div class="carousel__item">-</div>
<div class="carousel__item">-</div>
<div class="carousel__item">-</div>
<div class="carousel__item">-</div>
<div class="carousel__item">-</div>
</div>
```